# How to quote bash flag arguments to pass through one getopts call and be interpreted by a second?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts, variable-expansion, delayedvariableexpansion

Script `nerf` calls script `herd`, which calls script `er`.  `nerf` uses a flag on `herd` that explicitly takes arguments needing to be passed to `er`.

This was not a problem before `nerf` existed - when `herd` was just called from the command line, we could single-quote the arguments to the -p flag, and they would never be interpreted by `herd`'s `getopts`, but instead they would be interpreted by `er`'s `getopts`.

But now we have generated values in the flags that eventually need to go to `er`, so I need to expand the variable `$file_contents` in `nerf`, but not let them be interpreted by `getopts` until they get to `er`.

Any of these three scripts can be modified.

```
$ cat nerf
#!/bin/bash
file_contents="`cat one_liner_file`"
er_args="-jkl -m $file_contents"
./herd -p "$er_args"              # <-- the problem


$ cat herd
#!/bin/bash
passthru_args=""
while getopts "p:a:b:cde" opt
do
  case $opt in
    p) passthru_args="$OPTARGS" ;;
    ...
  esac
done
./er "$passthru_args"


$ cat er
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "jklm:" opt
do
  case $opt in
    ...
  esac
done
```

If I use single quotes on the marked line above, I get the literal string "$er_args" passed through.  Using double quotes, the flags are directly interpreted by `herd`.  Using single inside double quotes, the flags aren't interpreted by ANY getopts.

I'm thinking there's no elegant solution here, but please let me know if I'm wrong.  The only solutions I can think of are crappy:

1. Expose all of `er`'s flags explicitly through `herd`.
2. Remove the `er` call from `herd` and place it directly into `nerf`.
3. ???

Comment: Consider a Bash array:  `passthru_args=()`; `passthru_args+=( "$OPTARGS" )`; and `./er "${passthru_args[@]}"`.

Comment: You'd also use an array in `nerf`, of course: `er_args=( "-p" "-jkl" "-p" "-m" "-p" "$file_contents")` and `./herd -p "${er_args}[@]}"`.  You should probably use `$(...)` in lieu of backticks in ``file_contents="`cat one_liner_file`"`` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What many tools do is when passed `-p "-jkl -m something"`, they split up the string using pseudo-shell syntax. This is a bad idea because it makes space and quote handling unpredictable.

Instead, the better way is to have a way to pass individual words to the command. This is what `find -exec` does -- all arguments after `-exec` and up until `+` or `;` are passed literally as separate arguments.

Here's a simple example of a `herd` with the same semantics:

```
#!/bin/bash
passthru_args=()
while getopts "pa:b:cde" opt
do
  case $opt in
    p)
      while [[ ${!OPTIND} != ';' ]]
      do
        passthru_args+=("${!OPTIND}")
        let OPTIND++
      done
      let OPTIND++
    ;;
    *) echo "herd: $opt is $OPTARG"
    ;;
  esac
done
./er "${passthru_args[@]}"
```

You can now run `./herd -p -jkl -m "some stuff" \; -a foo`

This will run `./er -jkl -m "some stuff"` safely without any space issues (but you'll have a hard time nesting multiple calls that use `;` as an argument terminator).

Comment: Awesome, OPTIND was the solution!  I made it configurable - either use the passthru flag -p as the last argument to herd, OR use the semicolon: `while [ -n "${!OPTIND}" ] && [ "${!OPTIND}" != ';' ]`.

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow. Nice! You can also compare `$OPTIND` to `$#` to allow empty arguments.

Comment: I must be tired, because it took me WAY too long to figure this out, so I'll point it out for anyone else: make sure, in your getopts string, you DO NOT put a colon after 'p'.  If you do, the next token after the -p flag is turned into an OPTARG, and is ignored when you're skipping through the OPIND indices.

Comment: but what oo you do if you want to pass something like `sshfs -o option="1 2"`